# text_field_tag in simple_form gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have this form with [simple_form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :description, :as => :text %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'post[tags]' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want write in simple_form format this line:

```
<%= text_field_tag 'post[tags]' %>
```

**How can I do it?**

Thank you!

Comment: Simple form automatically determines the correct tag, depending on the type of model fields. You can also specify the type of field.
Can you explain the situation more, because I do not understand why you can not do simply: f.text_field :tags - simple form support this syntax.

Comment: thank you @MikhailD it does works fine `f.text_field :tags` :). Thank you very much

Comment: I moved comment into answer. Can you accept this, if it's still correct? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple form automatically determines the correct tag, depending on the type of model fields. You can also specify the type of field (as in `form_for`): `f.text_field :tags` - simple form support this syntax.

Comment: It returns `undefined method `merge' for :tags:Symbol` . I'm looking for a generic tag I can use and clone..